# Syncing between perforce and git

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

Does anyone have a solution to sync commits automatically between Perforce and Git?

A lot of people wish to use perforce, but we also have a lot who wish to use git and it appears impossible to convince everyone either way. What we're looking for is to sync changes between git repositories and perforce servers, so any changes committed to one also get submitted to the other.

Does anything like git-p4 or git fusion allow for this? Are there just some simple scripts which can do the translation and committing? I suppose I could write one myself, but it would be much better and less error-prone if there was an existing solution. I can't imagine I'm the first one to encounter such a problem.

Thanks

Comment: So Perforce remains the 'master' which Git will pull/push against?

Comment: Assume Git user commits a code and creates a conflict with a code that Perforce user committed 3 sec ago. Your sync script or whatever will break all the time and requires manual intervention.

Comment: That's fairly unlikely to happen if the sync is fast enough. I don't mind resolving conflicts manually if necessarily as long as the syncing can handle it gracefully. I'd prefer there is no master/slave, since that would mean we couldn't really take advantage of some features of git if perforce is the master.

Comment: I did this a while ago, but unfortunately I no longer have the scripts. It's fairly straightforward, but you need to be careful of locking since you will need to rewrite git history to match Perforce's history. I used gitolite, and a git pre-commit hook to lock out pushes while the git-p4 rebase was happening.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at Perforce's Git Fusion product, or it's Git Swarm product.

http://www.perforce.com/git